# Is it possible to create POSIX applications in VB6

Tags: vb6, posix

Is it possible to create POSIX applications in VB6?
And how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. VB6 produced Win32 executables only. No version of Visual Basic has ever created `POSIX` applications.

Comment: Not AFAIK with VB6. You could with earlier versions, but I don't recall that option with VB6. Even if you could, though, they'd be Win16 applications and not POSIX. VB has never done anything except Windows applications.

Comment: @Deanna: I wasn't aware that even existed. :-) Thanks for the info, though; if I ever get transported back to 1991, I'll remember to look for it. (Probably not, but it's something I didn't know about, anyway. :-) ) The actual question here, though, was about VB6. (Just checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), and see that VB for DOS (VB 1.0) was the first version after QuickBasic; that's why I wasn't aware. By then I'd long moved on to other languages (C and Clipper). :-) By VB 2, they'd dropped the 'for DOS', and it was just VB.

Comment: Actually VBDOS was a successor to PDS7, which followed QuickBasic.  I've never seen any VB2 that compiled DOS programs.

Comment: @Bob: That's what I said. :-) Except I wasn't aware of VBDOS at all, so I didn't think any version of VB did. The version history I gave in my comment came from the linked Wikipedia article, so whether PDS7 was between QB and VBDOS I don't know. (As I said above, I left BASIC long before VBDOS would have been released.)

Comment: @SEARAS: No, it was in reply to KenWhite about it only creating Windows apps. There was a DOS version. Your best bet for creating a posix compliant application is to use a posix compliant language/framework.

Comment: @SEARAS I've removed my vbdos comment, I suggest all replies to it are removed for clarity. This comment will self destruct shortly.

Comment: PLEASE , REMOVE ODD COMMENTS (I will remove this after all odd comments are removed).

Comment: @Ken White where can I find Frob Basic? I googled, but found nothing. Google thinks I must type "From Basic" , not "Frob Basic" :)

Comment: @SEARAS: That was a joke, making sure that people knew I wasn't referring to anything but *Visual* Basic. AFAIK, there is no `FROB` basic.

Answer (score -3):

OK. All this means that Visual Basic basically uses libraries made for Windows, consequently it can't create applications for other platforms such as POSIX subsystem.

Comment: It's great that you answered, but in the future you can just accept the answer that told you this :)

Comment: I think reading only this post is much easier than reading that post and all comments with it ;) But thanks for that great post. @Tim Post thanks for editing:)

Comment: What is hard to understand about the ["No, it is not"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12569151/588306) from the other answer that contains almost exactly what you wrote?